# how to fetch data with nextjs from backend API end point in production

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have been stuck for a very long time. Sorry if it is a silly question and/or duplicate but I did not find anything on google.

Basically I finished my project and I am trying to deploy it on Heroku.

Normally I would call the backend API from the components like this

```
fetch(http://localhost:8090/shop, {some code})
```

if I wanted to get the logic of the route /shop.

I was able to deploy everything on Heroku but the API end point is not being called.

I tried the following:

- replaced `http://localhost:8090/shop` with `${window.location.hostname}/shop`;
- replaced with `${window.location.host}/shop`;
- replaced with `${window.location.host}:8090/shop`;
- replaced with just `/shop`;
- replaced with `e-commerce-my-shop/shop`;
- replaced with `https://e-commerce-my-shop/shop`.

None of these solution worked in my case. What do I need to put into the fetch in order to call the right API end point and so have the logic placed in that middleware? The name of the app on Heroku is e-commerce-my-shop so the url is `https://e-commerce-my-shop.herokuapp.com/`

This is the first time that I deploy something on a platform so sorry again if it is a silly question.

If, for some reasons, I am going against stackoverflow policies, please let me know and I will update my question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Doesn't heroku give you a permanent URL to the instance?

Comment: yes, it is `https://e-commerce-my-shop.herokuapp.com/`, sorry if it wasn't clear

Comment: Have you tried using an environment variable to set the base URL for your API calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the URL in an [environment variable](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables). You can have a local and production .env file. When you build the app Next will use the production file.

Because your calls are in the browser you're going to need to prefix your env variables with [NEXT_PUBLIC](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser).

In your root you need to create two files with the file names - .env & .env.local - Restart Next every time you add or edit variables.

.env.local - dev

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=localhost:8090
```

.env - production

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=https://e-commerce-my-shop.herokuapp.com
```

You'd use it thoughout your app like

```
fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/shop`, {some code})
```

Often when you deploy your code to a third-party service like Heroku, GitHub Actions, AWS lambda, or other serverlesss platforms, the environment variables are not automatically included as they do on a dev machine.  You likely need to [set the env variables in their platform separately](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Lastly, if you are using git, you should never [commit your .env files](https://dev.to/somedood/please-dont-commit-env-3o9h).

Comment: Why does the variable name need to start with `NEXT_PUBLIC`? Since you declare the variable in `.env`, it can be whatever you want.

Comment: I think it's a way to tell Next where the env is needed - server or client. - If the variable was only in the API it wouldn't need the prefix.   Since the client needs access they have to be prefixed -https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser

Comment: it did not fix my problem (just because probably the issue is something else) but I did implement this in my code and I also did not know this. Thank you!

Comment: I added an update - you probably didn't know to set the env vars to match your site in Heroku.